# how to use colab so that it recognize a folder of my Google Drive

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I have downloaded the IMDB dataset and copy it into my Google Drive under the folder imdb, the issue that I have is that I am not able to manipulate this folder under colab. Supposedly it is in My Drive and looking at the solutions I have done the following:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

It asks for an authentication code and I have put it. However, when I do the following:

```
imdb="imdb"
trainD=os.path.join(imdb,"train")
testD=os.path.join(imdb,"test")
testlabels=[]
testtexts=[]
print(trainD)
trainlabels=[]
traintexts=[]
for labelType in ["neg","pos"]:
  dirName=os.path.join(trainD,labelType)
  print(dirName)
  for fName in os.listdir(dirName):
    if fName[-4:]==".txt":
      f=open(os.path.join(dirName,fName),encoding="utf8")
      print(f)
```

The following error appears:

RROR:root:Internal Python error in the inspect module.
Below is the traceback from this internal error.

```
imdb/train
imdb/train/neg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2882, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-26-a6dd3dffb70e>", line 12, in <module>
    for fName in os.listdir(dirName):
OSError: [Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected: 'imdb/train/neg'
```

However this subfolders are available: train and test. I can read these folders using Anaconda in a local drive, but not in Colab. Any help?

Comment: On the left side, you can see the folder structure you're working in. Google drive is connected at `/content/drive`, so you need this prefix for all paths to all files and folders in your drive. If you want to change to be working "in your drive", i.e. that e.g. `open("foo.txt")` will open `/content/drive/foo.txt` automatically, you can do `import os; os.chdir('/content/drive')` (chdir = change working directory).

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you should use an absolute path to reach your content on your Drive and that's why you can't open your text file. Try to replace imdb variable's value to this:

```py
"/content/drive/MyDrive/path_to_your_imdb_folder/..."
```

Do not forget to configure the path after from MyDrive folder.

I hope it will work.

Answer (score 1):

1. after run the code below, you get authentication Url and must log in
   with google account after log in you get code then paste in box.

   ```
   from google.colab import drive
   drive.mount('/content/drive')
   ```
2. little change your code on path, maybe this help you:

   ```
   imdb="/content/drive/MyDrive/imdb"
   trainD=os.path.join(imdb,"train")
   testD=os.path.join(imdb,"test")
   testlabels=[]
   testtexts=[]
   print(trainD)
   trainlabels=[]
   traintexts=[]
   for labelType in ["neg","pos"]:
     dirName=os.path.join(trainD,labelType)
     print(dirName)
     for fName in os.listdir(dirName):
       if fName[-4:]==".txt":
         f=open(os.path.join(dirName,fName),encoding="utf8")
         print(f)
   ```